# How do I pass string parameter that has encoding problem from terminal?

Tags: python, encoding, visual-studio-code, terminal, character-encoding

I'm trying to pass a string parameter that has Korean characters. This causes an error, because Korean characters are apparently not properly encoded/decoded before it is passed to `open()` built-in function.

I wrote a command then executed it with `os.system()` which is equivalent to running it on the command prompt.

```
command = 'hwp5txt "C:\\Users\\username\\VSCodeProjects\\myproject\\data_files\\some_folder\\hwp\\2020-01-17_-_한국어가포함된 파일명(2020년도 제1차).hwp" > testdoc.txt'

os.system(command)
```

This throws an error because Korean characters are not properly decoded.

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\asiae-bok-nlp-xpMr0EW7-py3.7\Scripts\hwp5txt-script.py",
>   line 11, in 
>       load_entry_point('pyhwp==0.1b12', 'console_scripts', 'hwp5txt')()          File
>   "c:\users\username\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\asiae-bok-nlp-xpmr0ew7-py3.7\lib\site-packages\hwp5\hwp5txt.py",
>   line 102, in main
>       with closing(Hwp5File(hwp5path)) as hwp5file:   File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\asiae-bok-nlp-xpmr0ew7-py3.7\lib\site-packages\hwp5\filestructure.py",
>   line 537, in **init**
>       stg = Hwp5FileBase(stg)   File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\asiae-bok-nlp-xpmr0ew7-py3.7\lib\site-packages\hwp5\filestructure.py",
>   line 188, in **init**
>       stg = OleStorage(stg)   File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\asiae-bok-nlp-xpmr0ew7-py3.7\lib\site-packages\hwp5\storage\ole.py",
>   line 35, in **init**
>       self.impl = impl_class(*args, **kwargs)   File "c:\users\uesrname\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\asiae-bok-nlp-xpmr0ew7-py3.7\lib\site-packages\hwp5\plat\olefileio.py",
>   line 112, in **init**
>       if not isOleFile(olefile):   File "c:\users\username\appdata\local\pypoetry\cache\virtualenvs\asiae-bok-nlp-xpmr0ew7-py3.7\lib\site-packages\olefile\olefile.py",
>   line 309, in isOleFile
>       with open(filename, 'rb') as fp: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:
>   'C:\Users\username\VSCodeProjects\asiae-BOK-nlp\data_files\BOK_minutes\hwp\2020-01-17_-_???????
>   ???(2020?? ?1?).hwp'

As you can see, `OS Error` was raised because the command I sent to the prompt somehow didn't manage to pass the right Korean characters, which is now `?????` instead of its proper name.

I tried it on the terminal manually but it also fails.

How do I pass string characters that is not properly passed to the module?

I'm using the latest version of VSCode with Git Bash terminal.

Also, I can check this information. If you need further information, please comment.

```
sys.stdout.encoding 
>> 'UTF-8'
sys.stdin.encoding 
>> 'cp1252'
sys.getfilesystemencoding 
>> 'UTF-8'
```

Comment: `os.system` calls the Windows `_wsystem` API. I'm not sure if there is a code page problem there. `subprocess` uses CreateProcessW and may work better. Try `subprocess.run(command, shell=True)` . Or run without the shell by making command a list `command = ["hwp5txt",  "C:\\Users\\username\\VSCodeProjects\\myproject\\data_files\\some_folder\\hwp\\2020-01-17_-_한국어가포>함된 파일명(2020년도 제1차).hwp"]` and then `subprocess.run(command, stdout=open("testdoc.txt", "wb"))`

Comment: It looks like your docx library throws the error. Is it up to date?

Comment: @tdelaney Sorry, no luck. Both of them return the error. As I said, the problem is that the correct file name is not getting to `\olefile\olefile.py`. By the time it gets there, it magically turns into useless `?????` string instead of correct file name.

Comment: @usr2564301 No, I believe `olefile` is throwing an error, but I don't think it's really `olefile`'s problem since the parameter value, which is the filename, is not even getting there in proper form. I don't know where it screws up and gives `?????` instead of the proper file name.

Comment: I think something tries to encode the string to cp1252. The ? is the traditional "I don't know what that is" character. I don't know if its your program or hwp5txt. You could write your own little python program `import sys;print(sys.argv)` and see if you get the same problem.

Comment: @tdelaney I tried making my own little .py script as you advised and by doing so, I've figured out that this issue was related with `hwp5txt.exe`, not Python itself nor VSCode terminal. Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, this wasn't Python's problem nor VSCode. It was just `hwp5txt`'s issue where `hwp5txt.exe` won't digest Korean `sys.argv`. It works by trying:
`$ hwp5txt-script.py 'C:\\...\\한국어가포함된파일.hwp'`

However, one thing that bugs me is that this script would work on the terminal but not on Jupyter Lab or .py script.

i.e,
`os.system(command)` or `subprocess.run(command, shell=True)` won't run.

Instead, they will raise an error popup that says:

> "This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this
>   action. Please install an app or, if one is already installed, create
>   an association in the Default Apps Settings page."

Comment: Googling "hw5txt" I came up with [pyhwp](https://pyhwp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), which has an `hw5txt.py` program in its [source](https://github.com/mete0r/pyhwp/blob/master/pyhwp/hwp5/hwp5txt.py) and that thing can be made into an .exe. It uses an argument parser called `docopt` that I've never seen before. If this is indeed the thing you are using, then getting hints from its source or even installing the package and using its python directly may help.